# Sort array of locations - zipcodes on Google back-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Does anybody know whether this is possible:

There is an array of zipcodes:
zipcodes length might be around 100

`var zipcodes = new Array("90037","10162","80260","33101","15238","66103", ...);`

User enters zipcode e.g. 73101 into search box and
Google API returns JSON - sorted array based on distance.

If the above is not possible could I at least get all those distances with one request?

Comment: The Google API can give you the latitudes / longitudes of each position, but the distance I think you'll have to calculate yourself

Comment: *Maybe* this helps but I don't think so https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix